# Why are all my observations being deleted (r)

Tags: r

filter function is deleting my observations.

```
 bres_tidy <- bres %>%  
     separate(col = "INDUSTRY_NAME", into = c("INDUSTRY_CODE", "INDUSTRY_NAME"), sep = ":") %>%  
     pivot_wider(names_from = EMPLOYMENT_STATUS_NAME, values_from = OBS_VALUE) %>% 
     mutate (SELF_EMPLOYED = (Full_time_employees + Part_time_employees) - Employment) %>%
     filter(INDUSTRY_CODE == "C" | INDUSTRY_CODE == "F") %>%
     select(-INDUSTRY_CODE)
```

This is the problem code it all runs but specifically the line
`filter(INDUSTRY_CODE == "C" | INDUSTRY_CODE == "F") %>%`
deletes all my observations in the object, this is severely annoying, does anyone know why its happening?

Comment: Would you mind providing some of your data? Otherwise it is difficult to reproduce your problem. Anyway, I would first check after the mutate with `head` or `view` what my data looks like and check if there are indeed any rows which contain these values.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.